# How to change the tab bar image color for selected and unselected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to change the color of a tab bar item in iOS app.

The child view controllers are embedded in an navigation controller.

I have added this code in AppDelegate which just changes the color of the text.

```
 [UITabBarItem.appearance setTitleTextAttributes:
 @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:38/255.0 green:54/255.0 blue:73/255.0 alpha:1.0]}
                                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 [UITabBarItem.appearance setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : kColorTabbarNavigationBarTint}
                                       forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

And inside the image assets,if I make the particular image to be rendered as original it works, but the selection color does not work for the image.

Please let me know what could be done.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You have to set selected image and un selected image for particular tab item

Comment: Yes i tried setting that in each of the viewcontroller classes, didn't work. should we not set the image in storyboard for tab bar items?

Comment: Yeah sure, You can set it from storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code : When you want to set programatically.

```
// get your TabBarController
//UITabBarController *tabBarController = self.tabBarController
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController; 
UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;

UITabBarItem *tabItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
[tabItem1 setSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectimg"]];
tabItem1.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectimg"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
tabItem1.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"deselectimg"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
tabItem1.title = @"xxxx";

UITabBarItem *tabItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
tabItem2.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectimg"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
tabItem2.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"deselectimg"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
tabItem2.title = @"xxxx";

UITabBarItem *tabItem3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
tabItem3.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectimg"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
tabItem3.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"deselectimg"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
tabItem3.title = @"xxxx";

UITabBarItem *tabItem4 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
tabItem4.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectimg"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
tabItem4.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"deselectimg"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
tabItem4.title = @"xxxx";
```

Or you can set it in storyboard, Select particular tab item and see below

[image]

Comment: For this should i have to set the image in tab bar view controllers in storyboard? or should i have to leave this empty?