# Multiple tab bar icons are in selected state in iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios7.1

In tab bar, only currently active item should be in blue colour. But in iOS 7, multiple item's image are in selected state (blue colour). Apart from iOS-7 i.e. iOS-8 and above, its working perfectly fine. [PFA screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMQ6m.png)

Comment: Can you share any code? You have to have a bug somewhere. Probably you use custom tabbars? Show also your appearance methods.

Comment: Its just added in Storyboard. No explicit code is written. And yes, tab bar item in storyboard is given as custom.

Comment: looks like a bug to me!!! I wonder why the three tab bar items are different!!!

Comment: I know its a bug, that's why I asked for help. Please if you can.

Comment: WIthout the data noone can help you. Paste screenshots of inspectors from your storyboard, show adequate code. We can't detect bug in "something" when we don't have this "something".

Answer (score 0):

Check your image in storyboard where you have set, I think you have provide same image for both state, Selected and Normal. This should be your problem.

[image]

Provide different image for both, selected image under Tab Bar Item and image under Bar Item. See above image.

Also you can refer this link. [How to change the tab bar image color for selected and unselected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33366425/how-to-change-the-tab-bar-image-color-for-selected-and-unselected/33366626#33366626)