# How to set image in uitabbaritem for default

Tags: ios

I am working in `UITabBarController`, when I am going to set image for tabs, the image does not appear for first time when view is open. I don't know how to resolve this problem.

This is the code I am using:

```
UIImage *prfimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profile_o.png"];
UIImage *selimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profile_o.png"];
UITabBarItem *tbP = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" image:prfimage tag:YES];
[self setTabBarItem:tbP];
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:247/255.0f green:148/255.0f blue:29/255.0f alpha:2.0f]];
self.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
self.title = nil;
```

Comment: Refer this link to set tab image. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33366425/how-to-change-the-tab-bar-image-color-for-selected-and-unselected/33366626#33366626

Comment: thanks for your response i am done it.

Answer (score 0):

by following way you can set.

```
 UITabBarItem *tabItem = controller.tabBarItem;
 tabItem.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"history"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

Comment: thanks for your response,but its not working for me.

Comment: @SandeepChaudhary May you pls write your entire function so i can check it out.